Aya ebpf's HashMaps seem not to update atomically
I'm trying to perform some actions only for the first packet of each network flow.
I am using a HashMap to save flows and check if it is a new one.
Even though the flows are recognized, sometimes, two temporally very close packets belonging to the same flow are printed twice, after which the flow is recognized correctly.
I declared this HashMap:

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Default)]
struct Flow {
    src_ip: u32,
    dst_ip: u32,
    src_port: u16,
    dst_port: u16,
    protocol: u8,
}

#[map]
static FLOWS: HashMap<Flow, u8> = HashMap::<Flow, u8>::with_max_entries(1024, BPF_F_NO_PREALLOC);


I use it like this in my xdp function:

if unsafe { FLOWS.get(&flow) }.is_none(){
        info!(
            &ctx,
            "NEW FLOW: SRC IP: {:i}, DST IP: {:i}, SRC PORT: {}, DST PORT: {}, protocol:{} ",
            flow.src_ip,
            flow.dst_ip,
            flow.src_port,
            flow.dst_port,
            flow.protocol
        );
        FLOWS
            .insert(&flow, &1, 0)
            .expect("failed to insert flow into map");

    } else {
        info!(&ctx, "Flow already detcted SRC IP: {:i}, DST IP: {:i}, SRC PORT: {}, DST PORT: {}, protocol:{} ",
            flow.src_ip,
            flow.dst_ip,
            flow.src_port,
            flow.dst_port,
            flow.protocol)
    }


My intention is to then do some actions only for the first packet of each network flow. Even though the flows are recognized, sometimes, two temporally very close packets belonging to the same flow are printed twice, after which the flow is recognized correctly.
Here is an example of the output:

[2024-04-15T00:21:17Z INFO  aya_app] NEW FLOW: SRC IP: 142.250.191.206, DST IP: 10.184.237.255, SRC PORT: 443, DST PORT: 57401, protocol:17 
[2024-04-15T00:21:17Z INFO  aya_app] Flow already detcted SRC IP: 142.250.191.206, DST IP: 10.184.237.255, SRC PORT: 443, DST PORT: 57401, protocol:17 
[2024-04-15T00:21:17Z INFO  aya_app] NEW FLOW: SRC IP: 142.250.191.206, DST IP: 10.184.237.255, SRC PORT: 443, DST PORT: 57401, protocol:17 
[2024-04-15T00:21:17Z INFO  aya_app] Flow already detcted SRC IP: 142.250.191.206, DST IP: 10.184.237.255, SRC PORT: 443, DST PORT: 57401, protocol:17 
[2024-04-15T00:21:17Z INFO  aya_app] Flow already detcted SRC IP: 142.250.191.206, DST IP: 10.184.237.255, SRC PORT: 443, DST PORT: 57401, protocol:17 


I suspect that the insertions do not happen atomically (perhaps on different CPUs) and so it happens that the map is not yet updated when the second package arrives.
Is this possible or is it for some other reason? Do you have any tips to fix it?
Here there is the complete code.
Thanks

Why is there an unsafe block around the get call?

Where is the #[map] attribute from?

This map is not std::collections::HashMap, but since I need to write an ebpf program using the Aya library, I am importing from aya_ebpf::maps::HashMap.
In this case the get function requires an unsafe call (it contains an UnsafeCell) and the insert method requires a shared reference.
As for the #[map] annotation I think it is needed to indicate the intention to instantiate an ebpf map, in any case its need is specified in the Aya documentation.

Please add additional details (i.e. the [mre]) to your question by [edit]ing, not via comments.

unsafe { MAP.get(...) } without any checks wether something else currently accesses the map is how you got in trouble because that's UB. Also a get followed by insert in two different statements trivially isn't atomic.

I found out that to make the get atomic I have to pass the flag "BPF_F_NO_PREALLOC" in the map declaration, but being two different instruction it is still not atomic.
There is a way to use a spinlock on a ebpf map in Aya? (Or at most to force the xdp program to run on one thread?)

Where is this program attached exactly? Did you try confirming your "different cores" hypothesis by printing the core ID with bpf_get_smp_processor_id?
